# Set xticks to unique values in df column - Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to insert the x-ticks to a figure by using the unique values from a pandas column. I'm continually updating the data so I want something that can handle this without me continually updating the axes manually. I've tried below but am getting an error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Item' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],                                
    'x' : [-8.0,-4.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,10.0,-2.0,4.0,8.0,7.5,1.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-6.5,2.5],
'y' : [0.0,1.0,-0.5,5.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0,0.0,-5.0,-2.0,-2.0,-7.0,-0.5,-1.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0,-0.0,5.0,3.5],     
   })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

sns.lineplot(data = df, 
            x = 'Item', 
            y = 'y', 
            ci = 68,
            ax = ax
            )

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, (df['Item'].unique()) + 1, 1))
```

Out:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can set `xticks` directly as `df.Item.unique()`:

```py
ax.set_xticks(df.Item.unique())
```

[image: xticks as unique items]